# Get rid of un-realizable space in hard disk Linux

Tags: linux, rhel, hard-disk

When the disk utilization is checked I get `/dev/vdb2` partition is more than 70% full. This is a partition with total space 84GB and 56GB already used.

```
# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        50G   23G   28G  45% /
devtmpfs        3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.9G  273M  3.6G   7% /run
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vdb2        84G   58G   23G  72% /log
/dev/vdb1       9.8G  4.6G  4.7G  50% /mnt/
/dev/vdb3       4.8G   10M  4.6G   1% /data
/dev/vdd1       9.8G  723M  8.5G   8% /var
/dev/vdc2       4.8G   11M  4.6G   1% /tmp
/dev/vdc3       4.8G  280M  4.3G   7% /var/log
/dev/vdc1       4.8G  3.2G  1.4G  71% /home
/dev/vdc5       4.8G  757M  3.8G  17% /var/log/audit
tmpfs           783M     0  783M   0% /run/user/1003
```

When I check for the file sizes within `/dev/vdb2`, I don't see that much(56GB) space is consumed by files.

```
# du -ah /log | sort -nr | head -9
570M    /log/gateway/repository/logs/http_access_2019-11-30.log
562M    /log/gateway/repository/logs/wso2carbon.log
152K    /log/portal
148K    /log/portal/repository
144K    /log/rsync
144K    /log/portal/repository/logs
140K    /log/rsync/carbon-rsync-logs
20K /log/portal/repository/logs/http_access_2019-11-30.log
16K /log/portal/repository/logs/http_access_2019-11-27.log.gz
```

It seems to be there is some unrecognizable space consumed.
How is it possible to recover this disk space?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @roaima. You are correct. Edited.

Comment: Not  a duplicate @roaima

Comment: Why not? It answers your question

Answer (score 0):

At the end of each day, we are shipping the logs from this server to another server. Filebeat is involved in shipping the logs. To filebeat these logs remain available because file descriptor in /proc/ filesystem is held open. Restarting filebeat resolved the issue.

```
sudo su -
service filebeat restart
```